# Google Location API

Tags: api, geolocation, location, geocoding, reverse-geocoding

I am looking to access Google's location API for individual (anonymous) location datapoints. I was wondering if this is possible, and the approximate size of the data (in numbers of users). Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Location of Google users won't be available to you without their consent, either [from an Android app](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/location) or a [website using W3C Geolocation](https://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html). Example: [this tool](https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/) uses W3C, but doesn't store locations.

Both will have different accuracy from user to user, depending on their location preferences and actual location.